# Relationship between the partition function and the Hamiltonian

Tags: path-integral, hamiltonian, partition-function

The quantum Hamiltonian $H$ is related to the partition function $Z$ of statistical mechanics by
$$ Z = \textrm{Tr} \; e^{-\beta H} $$

But [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#The_path_integral_and_the_partition_function) uses Feynman's path integral formulation of QM to derive that
$$ Z = \textrm{Tr} \; e^{-HT / \hbar} $$

It's very counterintuitive to me that these two expressions would both give the same result, given that $\beta = (k_BT)^{-1}$. Is the second formula correct? If so, is there a simple way to see that the two expressions are equal?

Comment: in the second formula iT is an imaginary time as wiki says

Comment: Ohhhhh thanks! I hadn't read closely and assumed $T$ was temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The second formula must be handle with care. It is possible to show that the thermodynamic partition function of a system described by an Hamiltonian $H$ may correspond to the path integral under some assumptions (see for example [here](http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ads-cft/L1.pdf) or look for a textbook as [that](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8229)) and steps

1. The Hamiltonian contains a term that is quadratic in the impulses (there is a gaussian integration over them, but I do not know if this step can be avoided in some way)
2. The theory is written the imaginary time using a Wick rotation $t\to-i\tau$
3. Imaginary-time direction is compactified with a certain finite time length $\beta$
4. Dynamical variables (or fields) must follow appropriate boundary conditions (periodic or anti-periodic) when winding over the imaginary time direction  (for example, anti-periodic for fermions and periodic for bosons).

If one follows this recipe, then *formally* it is possible to say that the path integral representation coincides with the thermodynamic partition function of the system with temperature given by
$$
\beta = 1/kT
$$
where $\beta$ is the length of the imaginary time interval.